# Is aps dictionary necessary in iOS notification payload? Can we have same payload for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just started working on notifications on iOS and it seems that apple has defined a format for payload to receive notifications.

So currently, I am using this payload and everything is working as expected. I am getting title, subtitle, body sound, image.

```
{"aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Introduction To Notification",
            "subtitle" : "Session 707",
            "body" : "New Notification Look Amazing"
        },
       "sound" : "default",
        "category" : "message",
        "badge" : 1,
        "mutable-content": 1
    },
    "attachment-url": "https://pusher.com/static_logos/320x320.png"
}
```

Lets say I want to have a single payload for both Android and iOS.

Is there a standard format defined in Android for notifications or can you set any data in Android and the client has to manually handle and display these notifications?

How can I create a payload which works for both?

Comment: @NayanSrivastava for iOS, apple has set a specific keys to display alerts. Is this the same case for android or can we give any JSON and show data in way we want

Comment: The payload you show:  Are you sending that from firebase console?  And you followed a firebase (FCM) code example to send it?  Or are you saying you first are doing an iOS test, based on an example for using Apple's push notifications (APNs)?  If my question is not clear, then show the code you are using in the iOS app, in order for notifications to work.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41562823/199364). Expand the comments - apparently the answer is "No, send separate payloads for Android and iOS users."  I've added a comment there, asking HOW to do so.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am sending the payload from pusher, basically i have done a iOS test and was succesfull, Just need to know is there a way we can create a payload which can work on both devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update for cross-platform payloads**: A recent feature was added for FCM that gives an option to provide specific params for specific platforms, called [Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms).

---

The sample payload you posted seems to be in-line with the [official parameters for APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html). When using [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) or [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json), the parameters to be used are different (see the links).

> *Is there a standard format defined in Android for notifications or can you set any data in Android and the client has to manually handle and display these notifications?*

It depends on which type of message payload you're planning to use. There are [2 types of Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for GCM/FCM, `notification` and `data`.

[`notification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) messages only have predefined set of parameters available, while [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) messages can be used to have custom key-value pairs. Both are usually handled by the client, but note that the behavior for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) are different depending on the message type you use (see the links).

> *How can I create a payload which works for both?*

As I mentioned in comments section in the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41562823/4625829):

> You'll have to do the mapping in your own database/app server. Yes. What I was thinking here was every time a registration token is generated on the client app side, you send it to your database/app server along the type of device (i.e. "Android", "iOS"). So that when you'll be sending messages, you'll first have to check the type of device. I did say it's more work, but it's a sure way to give you control over things. AFAIK, it is the developer's responsibility to keep track of the registration tokens and any details that should be associated with it.

Comment: so you are suggesting to use separate payloads for iOS and Android, right ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta Yup.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to put custom tags inside aps tag. Here's what documentations says about it:

Providers can specify custom payload values outside the Apple-reserved aps namespace. Custom values must use the JSON structured and primitive types: dictionary (object), array, string, number, and Boolean.
So in your case you should do something like:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello World",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "Person": {
        "Address": "Your address",
        "Name": "Your Name",
        "Number": "XXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

Therefore you can read your custom payload with looking for it's key in main JSON, rather than in "aps":