# How to handle differrent payload of notification to Android and iOS in a same time using php FCM?

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I using FCM to send notification for Android and iOS apps via my php server.Just because the different payload need by different platform,now I facing a big problem.

**Now my payload structure look like this**

```
"registration_id":[all my firebase token here]
 //***here just for iOS
 "notification":{
    "title":"Match update",
    "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
    "sound" : "default"
    "priority" : 'high'
    "content_available" = true
 }
 //***here I need this for Android
"data":{
   "title":"Match update",
   "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
   "id": "my_id"
    //other data I need in android
}
```

So by sending the payload I actually get the notification in iOS and Android at the same time.Which is good,but..

**The real problem start here..**

In android,I dont have my app scan for the `notification` field,I want to handle my app when the notification arrive in Android device start from "data" field.Although I dont have get data in the "notification",the app seem automatically handle for me for the "notification" data.

But if I not include the "notification" field in the payload above,Android part is behave as what I want,but in iOS,I unable to get the notification at all.

After look at this **Platform Override** mention in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48478600/4332049),I modify my payload like below:

```
"registration_id":[all my firebase token here]
"android":{
  "data":{
        "title":"Match update",
        "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
    }
}
"apns":{
   "payload":{
            "aps":{
               "alert":{
                  "title":"Hello",
                  "body":"Please confirm your availability"
               }
            "sound" : "default"
            "priority" : 'high'
            "content_available" = true
            }
}
```

But with the payload structure above,both my Android and iOS cant receive any notification.

Note: Both my Android and iOS app can get notification from Firebase console.

So my question is : How to send different structure of payload to different platform to solve this kind of dilemma?

Comment: make two calls ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I cant,cause all ios and android fcm token is inside 1 same array

Comment: `registration_id` is not a key for FCM v1. Currently, you can send to a single device using the `token` key, to a topic using the `topic` key, or to topic conditions using `condition`. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices) for more information and a complete list of [payload options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages).

Comment: @JenPerson so in this case I need a for loop to call the firebase API 1 by 1 for all token inside the array??

Comment: That is one option. Or you can use topics. Or you can use a batch request, which uses notation similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch). We're working on incorporating batch notation into the FCM documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Please read the documentation about platform-specific messaging.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms)

The sample message from that page looks like this:

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification"{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5",
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Your JSON doesn't seem to be structured like that at all.  Try copying the sample structure and working from there, paying attention to the nesting of the various elements.

Comment: Is it possible to use two different `title` and `body` to android and ios?